# User.Identity.Name throw Object reference not set to an instance

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, windows-authentication

I have this code

```
public UserProfile spUserProfileGet()
        {
            // this line throw : Object reference not set to an instance 
            var user = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;

            //...

        }
```

In my IIS Development setting, I have

```
Anonymous Authentication : Disabled
Windows Authentication : Enabled
```

And i am getting

```
Object reference not set to an instance
```

Why is that ? I am using this class in many projects before with no problem :/

The `HttpContext.Current.User` is `NULL`, but why ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: yes, the User object is NULL, but why ?

Comment: Read the duplicate question, it tells you exactly how to figure that out.

Comment: @DavidG in this case generic advice on debugging null references is unlikely to help. If `User` is null it points to an issue with auth configuration.

Comment: Maybe, the cause is that I use it in `Application_BeginRequest()` method and there is no user object yet, I will inspect this

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, that I called `HttpContext.Current.User` from global.asax `Application_BeginRequest()` which does not contain this object yet. Here is description of application lifecycle https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx and when I copy the code to the
`Application_PostAuthenticateRequest`, It works now.

The problem that remains, is that `Application_PostAuthenticateRequest` is triggered twice.